# API version BigQuery in Google Dataflow python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Could someone tell me if the current API version of BigQuery to use with Google Dataflow in python is 0.25?

When I install apache-beam using:

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

The version I get is: 0.25

But the final version of the BigQuery API's for Python is 1.7.x

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Beam uses `google-cloud-bigquery` just for [testing](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.8.0/sdks/python/setup.py#L146) purposes. The connections made to BigQuery (or any other GCP tool) uses a proprietary [client](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.8.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/bigquery/bigquery_v2_client.py) based on [apitools](https://github.com/google/apitools) since the code must prioritize performance as much as possible.